# How to create test spec for angular 2 service with @Inject contructor

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

I am having a problem creating a unit test for my translate service. I have this as a constructor of my **TranslateService**

```
constructor(@Inject(TRANSLATIONS) private _translations: any) {}
```

I created **my translate.service.spec.ts** with this

```
describe('On initialize', () => {
        it('No changes made to the service', async(inject([TranslateService], (service: TranslateService) => {
            let translate = TestBed.get(TranslateService);
        })));
    });
```

However, the console prompts me with an error saying, "**No provider for TranslateService**". How inject the @Inject in the spec file?

Comment: Had you imported `TranslateService` in your `my translate.service.spec.ts`?

Comment: @Poonam Yes, I have imported it.

Comment: Have a visit on this [https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html)

Comment: I have visited the site. However, it does not show an @Input with the same specifications as the one above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using this

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: TRANSLATION, useClass: TranslationService }
  ]
});
```

Then you need to do this

```
it('should inject', inject([TRANSLATION], (value: TranslationService) => {

}));
```

The `provide` specifies the *token* for which we can inject. Since the token isn't `TranslationService`, we can't inject `TranslationService`. We need to inject by the token `TRANSLATION`

---

### UPDATE

Is the inject is in the `TranslationService`

```
class TransactionService {
  constructor(@Inject(TRANSLATION) value) {}
}
```

Then you should probably do something more like

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    TranslationsService,
    { provide: TRANSLATION, useValue: whateverTranslationIs }
  ]
});

it('should inject', inject([TranslationService], (value: TranslationService) => {

}));
```

You need to configure the `TRANSACTIONS` injectable in the test bed configuration

Comment: I have tried using the method you can said. But it still creates an error in the console. 
` Error: Provider parse errors: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! Token_translations: in NgModule DynamicTestModule`

Comment: Here is a plunker containing the code
https://plnkr.co/edit/DWwIGSfx3A2YZEHTCdfs?p=catalogue